# Laravel Scout - The relationship is not added at creation

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, algolia, laravel-scout

PHP: 7.3

Laravel: 5.8

Laravel Scout: 7.1

Algolia Scout extended: 1.6

```
class Page extends Model
{   
  use Searchable;

  public function toSearchableArray()
  {
    $array = [
      'title' => optional($this->content)->title,
      'extra' => $this->extra,
    ];

    return $array;
  }

  public function content()
  {
    return $this->morphOne(Content::class, 'contentable');
  }

  protected $fillable = ['extra'];

  protected $with = ['content'];
}

class Content extends Model
{
    public function contentable()
    {
      return $this->morphTo();
    }

    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    protected $touches = ['contentable'];
}

class PageController extends Controller
{
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $page = Page::create($request->all());

    $page->content()->create($request->all());

    return $page;
  }

  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $page = $this->findOrFail($id);

    $page->update($request->all());

    $page->content->update($request->all());

    $page = $page->fresh();

    return $page;
  }
}
```

Scout import of existing instances works fine, all instances are in sync.

On update the sync works fine, $touches does the job.

```
$array = [
  'title' => 'Title',
  'extra' => 'Extra field',
];
```

***On store the content relation is null and not updated when is created.***

It looks like it does not listen to the **content** **saved** event. (The relation is added into the **$touch** array).

```
$array = [
  'title' => null,
  'extra' => 'Extra field',
];
```

Comment: i didn't understand whats your question?

Comment: The problem is on store method. It does not append the content relation data. On update works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
    $page = Page::with('Content')->findOrFail($id);

    $page->update($request->all());

    $page->content->update($request->all());

    $page = $page->fresh();

    return $page;
  }
```

it will work

Comment: Update works fine as I said. The problem is on store method.

Answer (score 0):

```
// use Content; // after namespace
class PageController extends Controller
{    
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    $page = Page::with('content')->create($request->all());

    return $page;
  }
try this step
```